# Push Notifications using Rails server

Tags: android, iphone, ruby-on-rails, push-notification

I have a rails server and a backend. Is it possible to send a push message using my rails server to both iPhone and android app?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Here are gems that I used recently in my projects: [Android push service](https://github.com/dondeng/gcm_on_rails) and [Apple push service](https://github.com/jpoz/APNS)

They are well documented so you should not face big troubles about setup.

Comment: I don't acyually know about Heroku, but it works under Rails 3.2.x in my project hosted on Linode.

Answer (score 8):

I created a gem in order to create a central push notifications, it supports iOS and Android at the moment, but i will add more platforms.

Maybe this will help you

here is the link: https://github.com/NicosKaralis/pushmeup

Answer (score 1):

Try using [grocer gem](https://github.com/grocer/grocer) for ios push notifications. Thats pretty easy to setup and get going.

Comment: It's better to use https://github.com/nomad/houston/tree/master/lib/houston instead of Grocer. I faced an issue with sending a series of pushes over Groces. Houston works like a charm.